# How to add 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' to JSON endpoint

Tags: json, http

The phrasing of this questions is probably indicative of naivety but as I understand JSON endpoints, they are a URL I can point to to grab JSON objects.

This error seems to indicate though that not all urls are the same. I've tried multiple methods of mocking a remote JSON endpoint:

1) I've used mockable.io which gives me a link. I can GET with that link but  POST or a GET gets me an Access-Control error.

2) I've tried pointing to a local json file. I can GET with this but  POST or GET throws a 501 not implemented error.

3) I tried hosting the folder locally then opening that port globally with ngrok so that any computer in the world can access the json file with ngrok391.whatever.com. This throws the Access-Control error even for a GET.

The only other time I've seen this error was with a different setup, tomcat and java. A friend did the backend mostly so I don't remember the specifics but we basically found a line somewhere and added Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *.

What is the relevant "thing" to do for what I'm trying to do now. Not sure what to call this "thing", possibilities include "allow cross-domain data access", "add a header to a json file" (w/e that means), or "easily get and post to a data file"

Comment: `POST` requires software on the server that knows what to do with the POST. What do you *expect* to happen?

Comment: Well I guess I'm assuming too much then, much like I'm sure you assume things to get by in life too. Do you have any advice on how to go about solving this issue of needing a mock data source but not needing an entire backend to be built.

Comment: You can start by answering the question: what is supposed to happen when you `POST` to the resource?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to test, and what library and language are you using for your client?

Comment: Client is completely in angular. I guess I am using the word POST without understanding it too much but I guess what I want it to do is "save". After my app GETs the data and the user manipulates it, I now have it locally but I'd like to replace the remote data with the local data on a button click or something.

Comment: I mean what specific part of your stack are you trying to test? See [AngularJS: Developer Guide: Unit Testing](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.unit-testing) for mocking the request object, so you can verify with what parameters it is being called without having to set up an HTTP stack.

Comment: I'm not really trying to test any part of my stack actually. I'd just like a persistent data store I can get and post data too. With mockable.io I can get data from a URL and feel like I should be able to overwrite/replace that with a post/put as well with a small change. But I'm getting the feeling this approach may be too naive and not possible. EDIT: I'm reading through your link btw to see if it helps.